# How to build multi step form using routes?

Tags: javascript, angular

- Should I use `localStorage` to store the user input?
- Should I create a `service`? Can anyone explain how do I achieve this approach?

For example:

I have 4 routes, each one has a form in it. The last route is going to submit everything.

```
//1th route 
this.formStepRoute1 = this.fb.group({
  inputRoute1: ['', [Validators.required]],
  radioRoute1: ['', [Validators.required]]
});

//2th route 
this.formStepRoute2 = this.fb.group({
  inputRoute2: ['', [Validators.required]],
});

//3th route 
this.formStepRoute3 = this.fb.group({
  inputRoute3: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
```

Or should I create a `service` and build a single `form` inside of it? How do I populate the user input (and how to keep stored) each time I change the `route`?

For example:

```
//Service
    
this.fb.group({
  step1: this.fb.group({
    inputRoute1: ['', [Validators.required]],
    radioRoute1: ['', [Validators.required]]
  }),
  step2: this.fb.group({
    inputRoute2: ['', [Validators.required]],
  }),
  step3: this.fb.group({
    inputRoute3: ['', [Validators.required]],
  })
});
```

Comment: Why you go for router ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Each team of our project are developing a form using routes.

Comment: If you go for route option then to inject service in each route, component is suitable for you.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda just like the second example that I gave? I don't need to store the data? I need to just inject the service (second example) in each component route and will it work? for ex (in the second route component ). this.serviceForm.get('step2.inputRoute2').setvalue('someUserIpdate')